# ＭｉｎＧＷ gcc コンパイラ　書き込み時にデレクトリがない。エラー

Tags: gcc, mingw

C:\Users\ob\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFJqNal.s
gcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
この、User/ob/ ここまでは、Ｗｉｎの Dir で、インストール時にできたものです。その先、Appdate~　などは作ってみましたが、やはり、File,Dir がない エラーになります。
Win でみると、ユーザー半角　文字になっています。
　これが原因ではないかとおもうのですが、どのような対策が
考えられるでしょうか？　英文字Ｕｓｅｒｓ＜　このホルダーは作れませんでした。（カタカナホルダーに統合される、）

mount コマンドで、しょうか？　よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージは

> ```
> gcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
> ```

であれば、`gcc.exe`を発見できず、何も実行できなかったことになります。まだ何も実行していないため、書き込みエラーも発生していません。

正しく環境が構築できているかを確認してください。

Comment: ＞であれば、gcc.exeを発見できず、　コマンドラインから、which gcc と聞くと、認識されているので、困っています。

Comment: @ＴＡＮＫＥＮｄｏｎ エラーの環境とコマンドラインは別ですよね？ コマンドラインからはコンパイル可能なのでしょうか？